# popup screen with background not in focus in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to design something like the image below

[image]

I have tired PopupWindow but the background still remain in focus.

Comment: Create DialogFragment with custom style having tag android:backgroundDimEnabled = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Custom Theme in style like this

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item></style>
```

and call this on Dialog you want.